# TypeError: string indices must be integers after SQL query to check if user is an admin

Tags: python

I'm working on a web app and am running into a `TypeError: string indices must be integers` error while implementing log-in. I'm using Python/Flask/sqlite. The goal is to check whether a user is an admin user during login. If they are admin, they will get redirected to different page than non-admin users. Here is the code snippet:

```
getuser = db.execute("SELECT username, isadmin FROM users WHERE id= :sid", sid=session["user_id"])[0]["username"]
isadmin = getuser[0]["isadmin"]
if isadmin >0:
  return render_template("admin.html")
return render_template("index.html", getuser=getuser, isadmin=isadmin)
```

Comment: try: `isadmin = getuser[1]`, does it work?

Comment: @OrY well the original `getuser[0]` is also an integer so I doubt the problem is there

Comment: @Geo please provide the full error traceback so it is easier to help you. In general, a working [mre] would be a good idea...

Comment: It turns out that the problem was with [0]["username"].   I dropped ["username"] and it worked.    
    isadmin = getuser["isadmin"]
    username= getuser["username"]
    if isadmin is None:
      return render_template("index.html", getuser=username)
    else:
        return render_template("admin.html", isadmin=isadmin,getuser=username)